# How to hide dropdown when a button inside it is clicked

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a drop down list as follows:

```
<div className="dropdown">
    <button className="nav-btn pick-a-sort">PICK A SORT:</button>
    <div className = "dropdown-content">
        <button className="nav-btn" id = "bubble-sort" onClick = {()=>{this.bubbleSort()}}>BUBBLE SORT</button>
        <button className="nav-btn" id = "selection-sort" onClick = {()=>{this.selectionSort()}}>SELECTION SORT</button>
        <button className="nav-btn" id = "insertion-sort" onClick = {()=>{this.insertionSort()}}>INSERTION SORT</button>
        <button className="nav-btn" id = "quick-sort" onClick = {()=>{this.quickSort()}}>QUICK SORT</button>
        <button className="nav-btn" id = "merge-sort" onClick = {()=>{this.mergeSort()}}>MERGE SORT</button>
        <button className="nav-btn" id = "bead-sort" onClick = {()=>{this.beadSort()}}>BEAD SORT</button>
        <button className="nav-btn" id = "heap-sort" onClick = {()=>{this.heapSort()}}>HEAP SORT</button>
        <button className="nav-btn" id = "radix-sort" onClick = {()=>{this.radixSort()}}>RADIX SORT</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have set the CSS such that the list is visible when the user "hovers" over the button "PICK A SORT:"

However, on clicking any of the buttons, unless the user moves the cursor out, the dropdown list stays visible as the cursor is still hovering over the list.

Is there a way to hide the list once a button inside the dropdown is clicked?

Here's my CSS:

```
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content .nav-btn{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

And here is the live [website](https://roy-05.github.io/sort-visualizer/) where you can see the problem. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a `clicked` class to the .dropdown container in your onclick function, and then add the follwoing CSS:

```
.dropdown.clicked:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
}
```

You'd have to then remove the `clicked` class at some point for the hover effect to work again.

Answer (score 0):

you may make parentnode styling display none onclick event.

```
<button className="nav-btn" id = "bubble-sort" onClick = {()=>{this.bubbleSort()}; this.parentNode.style.display = 'none';}>BUBBLE SORT</button>
```

Or you may make a common function to call it which will make the parentNode display none like below

```
let displayNone = (el) => el.parentNode.style.display = 'none';

<button className="nav-btn" id = "bubble-sort" onClick = {()=>{ this.bubbleSort()};  displayNone(this); }>BUBBLE SORT</button>
```